# Why can't I rebuild some SQL Server indices?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, fragmentation

I've got a table in my SQL Server 2005 database with two indices that are heavily fragmented (33.3% and 85.7%).  The table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Seasons](
   [SeasonID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
   [TeamID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Seasons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [SeasonID] ASC )
```

The other index is on the TeamID column.  When I attempt to rebuild the indices in management studio it tells me 'success' on each one.  But, when I view the fragmentation again nothing has changed.  The table only has 2300 rows in it.  Not sure if this is relevant, but I also noticed that it takes a LONG time (on the order of 30 seconds) to pull up the fragmentation info when I right-click an index, choose properties, and then select the Fragmentation page.

Other indices in the DB rebuild without a problem.

Any idea why I can't *actually* rebuild these indices?  Any idea why it takes sooo long to pull up the fragmentation information?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jon,

2300 rows and based on your schema, each row occupies about 118 bytes and in total comes around about 65 pages. In SQL Server a page is about 8 KB and you might already know this. In these small tables, fragmentation is NOT a big deal and you don't have to worry about them.

Initially space is allocated to tables as a single page allocation and once it has upto 3 extents then it will a uniform extent. The first few single page allocations spike up the fragmentation info. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same thing on the fragmentation option, I find it easier to use DBCC SHOWCONTIG WITH ALL_INDEXES, TABLERESULTS to get the stats for all tables at once, or just do one table.

And I wouldn't worry about fragmentation levels on smaller tables, it seems they don't defragment sometimes, not sure if it's a fault in the defrag process, or the calculation of the fragmentation level, but with a couple of thousand rows it's not going to affect performance.